# flyway supported database

Tags: database, flyway

We have seen flyway framework for database migration. We are very keen to implement same in one of our project. We use Sybase database in our project however we did not find Sybase as a [supported database](http://code.google.com/p/flyway/wiki/SupportedDatabases) in flyway documentation.

Could you please let us know if it does work for Sybase or will Sybase support will come in future.

Comment: Quoting the documentation mentioned above: "*If your database is not on this list, please [raise an issue](http://code.google.com/p/flyway/issues/list) and we'll see what we can do to support it.*"

Comment: @Tomasz your comment is the answer. Just make it one... :-)

Comment: @AxelFontaine: this is not technically an answer, but I cannot argue with the creators of the library in questions :-).

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/flyway/wiki/SupportedDatabases) :

> If your database is not on this list, please [raise an issue](http://code.google.com/p/flyway/issues/list) and we'll see what we can do to support it.

On one hand Flyway only executes SQL statements. On the other hand it needs to be database dialect-aware (statement delimiters, comments) to split SQL statements correctly. I guess it is not a big issue to support Sybase, but looks like it is not supported yet.

If you raise an issue, make sure to post a link to it here.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question was asked long time ago, however, i could say that right know Flyway support's Sybase, as you could see on [documentation](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/database/sybasease)

Right now most common Sybase version is 15.70 which is supported by Flyway 5.X community edition and Flyway 6.X enterprise edition.